# How do I use pivot/groupby for one column and concatenate others?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot

I would like to make a pivot/table summary based on one column (Month) and concetenete other columns. The key here is I wont know the column names expect (Month and Calculated) So the column names of info1 an info2 may change, **thus I cannot hard code them**, but I can hard code Month and Calculated. input is : [image: input]

I have already tried pivot tables and it is not showing all the columns and not doing what I need.

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import OrderedDict

d = {'Month': [1, 2, 2],
     'Calculated': [300, 400, 460],
     'info1': ["my info", "i really need the tech", "some more info"], 
     'info2': ["sales are good", "lets do more tech", "my third line"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.to_csv("myfile.csv")


df1 = df.pivot_table(index = ['Month'], aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index()

df1.to_csv("myfile1.csv")
```

I expected that all columns will be there, grouped by Month and concatenate other columns. Expected output is [image: expected output]

Please don't worry about the csv part, I did it to take a screenshot for this question.

**Solution:**

```
df.astype(str).pivot_table(index = ['Month'], aggfunc=lambda x: '\n'.join(x)).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need change the datatype first using `astype(str)`

```
df.astype(str).pivot_table(index = ['Month'], aggfunc=lambda x: '\n'.join(x)).reset_index()
```

Comment: It doesn't produce the expected output

Comment: Thanks alot! it helps. One quick follow up question, it changed the order of the columns. What can I do if I want Month and Calculated to show first. (It sent the calculated to the very end)

Comment: @shaucha `df.astype(str).pivot_table(index = ['Month'], aggfunc=lambda x: ' '.join(x)).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns)` add reindex at the end, it will make sure you out have the same order on columns as original df

Comment: @user32185 what you mean  ?

Comment: @Wen-Ben thanks! works great, I just added "\n" and it works great.

Comment: @shaucha yw :-) happy coding

Comment: @Wen-Ben you should use `"\n".join` instead of `" ".join`

Comment: @user32185 ok :-)